# Error changing geometry in oracle table by qgis

Tags: qgis, oracle-spatial, srid

I'm having a problem changing or adding geometry in QGIS. My database is Oracle.

I change my geometry in QGIS and when I go to save it, I get this message:

> SQL: ORA-29877: failed in the execution of the ODCIINDEXUPDATE routine
> ORA-13365: layer SRID does not match geometry SRID ORA-06512: at
> "MDSYS.SDO_INDEX_METHOD_10I", line 270

I've configured QGIS to always open in the correct SRID, so I have no problem loading geometry, doing filters or anything else. I researched on the internet that this was necessary because Oracle uses the `MDSYS.USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA` and the SRID is stored differently.

I realized that this error happens because I have an index key in the `USER_INDEXES` table, I did a test and removed the index from that table, and that way the system writes the information correctly. But I can't give up this index as it is used for other things like filters and even performance.

Does anyone have an idea what I could try?